# Which other programming languages apart from Python and predecessor are out there using indentation to define code blocks?

Tags: programming-languages, python, syntax

[Python](https://www.python.org/) quite famously uses indentation to *syntactically* define blocks of code. (See [Compound statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html) in the Python Language Reference). After years of using Python I'm still intrigued by and very fond of this syntax feature.

But I wonder: Apart from Python and its "predecessor"(*) language [ABC](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~steven/abc/programmers/quick-look.html) **which other programming languages are out there using indentation for definition of code blocks**? *Code blocks* means here "multiple statements which in some way are treated as one component".

I'm particularly interested in *practical* programming languages, but [*esoteric* languages](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language) might be worth mentioning as well.

---

(*): "*Predecessor*" is my choice of word in default of knowing here a better one. Guido van Rossum, the creator of Python, described the relationship between Python and ABC regarding indentation [in an interview](https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2014/02/16/open-heart-with-guido-van-rosuuma-lost-interview-of-python-creator-part2/) like this: "*The choice of indentation for grouping was not a novel concept in Python; I inherited this from ABC.*"

Comment: I don't think "please give me a list of programming languages with feature X" is a computer science question.

Comment: Honestly, I would just replace the word "predecessor" with "ABC." You only mean the one specific language by it, and that ABC inspired Python's whitespace rules is probably not widely known.

Comment: Why, there's the [Whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)) language itself that requires proper indentation for it's core method of expression.

Comment: Long-form YAML is probably worth mentioning even though it's not a programming language in the strictest sense, as it's probably one of the next most likely languages with this feature for someone to encounter after Python.

Comment: @penguin359 I also thought of Whitespace. It's not an answer to the question because indentation is, afaict, not used to define blocks; but it's certainly the language in which white space is most significant overall.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Grouping by attribute (i.e. categorization) is definitely a part of science: E.g. an interesting question for a Biology StackExchange could be: "*What other animals walk on two legs?*" Therefore I consider the above question very appropriate for the Computer Science StackExchange.

Comment: @halloleo Computer science isn't biology and questions that might be appropriate there (and note that "Please give me a list of X" is off-topic on most of Stack Exchange) aren't necessarily on-topic, here. Classifying things that humans have designed by a property that their designers deliberately chose them to have is very different from classifying un-designed things found in the natural world.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I agree, one could answer "there is an infinite number of such programming languages" which is arguably the best answer computer science can provide to this question. It's that easy to invent a new one. (BTW, this question was just featured in the HNQ)

Comment: @chi are there infinitely many now? Can you prove that?

Comment: @JJJ The proof is trivial. Define L0=Python, add the command `foo1` which does nothing. That's another language L1. Then add the command `foo2` and obtain L2, etc. Voila, infinitely many distinct (and Turing powerful!) languages which rely on indentation.

Comment: @chi that might satisfy some computer scientists, but I bet some people will argue that those languages are not actually *"out there"*. While I applaud your enthusiasm in coming up with a proof, you should look at the definitions first and, when those are ambiguous, ask for clarification.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! We don't have a strict policy for list questions, but there is a [general dislike](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). Please note also [this](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20) and [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/145/) discussion; you might want to improve your question as to avoid the problems explained there. If you are not sure how to improve your question maybe we can help you in [chat]?

Comment: @JJJ I do understand that my "answer" is unsatisfactory (and tongue-in-cheek, since it focuses on the letter and not on the spirit of the question), but my point is that this is CS.SE. From a CS point of view, what languages are "out there" is not truly relevant, and this question is not on-topic here if that matters. On, say, SE.SE or on a more general forum what's "out there" would instead be crucial -- it's a matter of context.

Comment: @chi that's a fair point. Too bad it wasn't migrated there, I think it's an interesting question. Trivia-ish, sure, but interesting nonetheless.

Comment: @chi + JJJ: So you guys think this question is better hosted on SE than on CS? Mmmmh, my question has indeed a social/historical angle to it, but isn't that still part of CS? (In the same way as the paper "[What is the Smallest Prime?](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Caldwell1/cald5.pdf)" is still a math paper.)

Comment: @halloleo It might have been better on SE, I think. At least in my mind, the historical angle is not the issue: history of CS is on-topic. The issue is that, say, in no CS book or scientific paper on programming languages I know of I can find a discussion on indentation. I can find that in SE language-specific books (e.g. "Programming in Python" books). This is because minor syntactic aspects of PL are not really studied by the PL scientific community: parsing is now a solved problem, and whether we use indentation or semicolons has no real effect on the design of a PL.

Comment: @halloleo Of course there is no clear line when theory/CS ends and practice/SE starts. I only use this criterion: in a university course about PLs I would never see indentation being discussed. In an university lab course, instead I would, since that's a practical necessity (especially if the PL which is being used mandates it). For this reason, I'm leaning towards SE instead of CS. (Others might have a different opinion, of course.) I don't think you have to ask for migration, though, since this was already completely answered anyway.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Wikipedia has an extensive list of languages that use the [off-side rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-side_rule)<sup>1</sup>:

> - ABC
> - Boo
> - BuddyScript
> - Cobra
> - CoffeeScript
> - Converge
> - Curry
> - Elixir (`, do:` blocks)
> - Elm
> - F# (if `#light "off"` is not specified)
> - Genie
> - Haskell (only for `where`, `let`, `do`, or `case ... of` clauses when braces are omitted)
> - Inform 7
> - ISWIM, the abstract language that introduced the rule
> - LiveScript
> - Miranda
> - Nemerle
> - Nim
> - occam
> - PROMAL
> - Python
> - Scheme, when using e.g. SRFI 119
> - Spin
> - XL

<sub>1: I've never heard this term before myself.</sub>

Comment: The off-side rule is an exciting find!

Comment: Don't know if it is a language as you or wikipedia understands it, but Makefiles use indentation too.

Comment: @TheWildHealer The wikipedia article also has a section with non-programming languages (including stuff like Make, YAML, RST). I didn't quote that because OP asked about programming languages.

Comment: You are right, next time I'll be sure to open my eyes, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

There are: [Elm](https://elmprogramming.com/indentation.html), [Haskell](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation), its predecessor [Miranda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miranda_(programming_language)) and its predecessor [ISWIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISWIM),
 [YAML](https://yaml.org/faq.html) where spaces are crucial for syntax and tabs are forbidden, [OCCAM](http://wiki.c2.com/?OccamLanguage), [Coffee script](https://coffeescript.org/) and [Cokescript](https://github.com/batiste/CokeScript) both are language to language compilers with JavaScript as target and esoteric [Whitespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)).

There is also [Agda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agda_(programming_language)) - interactive theorem prover, which is probably not what you had in mind, but its lexer is very sensitive to white-space.
[Makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)), which gathers targets with tab-based intends.

Comment: Also Miranda, the language Haskell was based on.

Comment: Agda has a very Haskell-like syntax, and is sensitive to both indentation and spaces: `(x-y)` is not `(x - y)`) even if it might not be "practical" enough for the OP.

Comment: Also, CoffeeScript and the hardly-known CokeScript

Comment: If YAML counts, then I suppose Makefiles must as well

Comment: Thank you all, I have updated post with your ideas, but I think it would be nicer if I could actually upvote your posts.

Comment: There is also [PureScript](http://www.purescript.org/).

Comment: A lesser known one would be BYOND (technically the language is called "DM", but good luck searching for that).

Comment: I guess Markdown would also count, at least in some cases (lists + code blocks)?

Comment: @Evil Thanks for starting this answers - and cool that you keep updating it from the comments. But I agree with *your* comment, that separate answers/posts have advantages, too.

Answer (score 4):

[Make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) fits your description, even though it probably isn't quite what you have in mind, with its limited syntax and power.

It [infamously](https://beebo.org/haycorn/2015-04-20_tabs-and-makefiles.html) indicates its code blocks (*recipes*) with a particular form of whitespace: one tab character. Alternative ways are available (e.g. [GNU Make supports using an alternative character](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Syntax.html#Rule-Syntax)), but rarely used in practice.

Another example hovering at the edge is [Ansible playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-language-example). They are specified in [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML), which is heavily indentation dependent. YAML is not a programming language, but Ansible playbooks can be regarded as domain-specific programs.